# How I can set automatically [L] Not to all?

Tags: powershell, confirm

My question is to powershell 7.2 switch [L] Not to all

I found information about -confirm but not a help how I can set automatic [L] 'Not to all' into  a function.
I will that not a user make a input.
-Confirm:$false, ConfirmPreference = "None" or 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted' is not a help.
The query comes every time. Do you have an idea / example how to set [L] to automatic?

[image: confirm question]

Comment: What's the actual cmdlet you're running? May just need a `-Force`.

Comment: $ConfirmPreference=”High”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's confirmation prompts aren't designed to be responded to *programmatically*; instead:

- Either: The *user* should decide, interactively.
- Or: The prompt should be *suppressed* altogether (*implying* a `[A] Yes to All` response), which *situationally* requires:

  - `-Confirm:$false`, for cmdlets that define a *confirm impact* (a rating of the potential destructiveness / risk associated with the cmdlet's operation) that can be controlled with the [common `-Confirm` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm) or the [`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference), such as [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)
  - `-Force`, for cmdlets that would otherwise *unconditionally* present a confirmation prompt, such as [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy).

    - The *caveat* is that `-Force` often has unrelated meanings in the context of other cmdlets, including in `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item`, where it is used to include hidden items in the enumeration / deletion.
  - In the case of [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item), specifically - *in addition* to the confirm-impact mechanism - you need `-Recurse` to signal the explicit intent to delete a directory *and all its contents*.

---

In your particular case, the equivalent of defaulting to `[L] No to All` would be to *not invoke `Remove-Item` at all if the target directory is non-empty*:

```sh
# Assume $dir contains the literal directory path of interest.
# Note that -Force in the case of Get-ChildItem causes inclusion of hidden items.
if (Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $dir | Select-Object -First 1) {
  Write-Error "Cannot remove directory $dir, because it is not empty."
} 
else {
  Remove-Item -LiteralPath $dir
}
```

Conversely, as stated, `Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force -LiteralPath $dir` would suppress the confirmation prompt, but quietly *go ahead* with the deletion (`[A] Yes to All` is implied).